# Unable to open a folder with space in cmd

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

I'm unable to open a folder in cmd. The folder name has a space

The script that I'm working on is

```
start D:\My Data
```

which does not work. However `start D:\MyData` seems to work

but I need the space in the folder name...

`start "D:\My Data"` just opens another cmd window:

[image: cmd]

Comment: anything with a space needs quotes around the entire pathname. `start "D:\My Data"`

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround the string with quotes otherwise the interpreter takes it as 2 separate strings

```
start "D:\My Data"
```

the compiler sees 2 strings: `start`, and `D:\My Data`
from `start D:\My Data` the compiler sees 3: `start`, `D:\My` and `Data`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hazzdod, i did try as suggested. the command just opened another command prompt window

Comment: and i found a similar thread https://superuser.com/questions/511486/how-to-start-open-a-file-folder-that-contains-space-in-its-name-through-command?noredirect=1&lq=1            start "" "d:\my data"  and  start "" "d:\R & D" worked